# How to create a Bootstrap table dynamically from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I don't know how to add dynamic JSON data in to the table without using any hardcoded headers. The data is fetched from the `data-url`.

```html
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"></table>
```

```js
$('#table').bootstrapTable({})
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap table API , you can see from here  https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/  , the data is loaded by the API itself

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. From the [documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/usage/#via-data-attributes) there it states that you have to define the columns of the JSON so that they can be mapped to the columns in your table. It does not allow you to dynamically load data without mapping the fields. If you need that behaviour I'd suggest finding another library or writing your own.

Comment: Yes that is the problem i am facing but  , here is a solution from stack overflow which i dont understand  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52863669/15512069

Comment: That solution is effectively the 'write your own' method which I mentioned above. If you're struggling understanding how it works I'd suggest researching AJAX and finding some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I found the answer

 var dataSet = [{
  Latitude: 18.00,
  state:"odisha",
  Longitude: 23.00,
  Name: "Pune"
}, {
  Latitude: 14.00,
  state:"odisha",
  Longitude: 24.00,
  Name: "Mumbai"
}, {
  Latitude: 34.004654,
  state:"odisha",
  Longitude: -4.005465,
  Name: "Delhi"
}, {
  Latitude: 23.004564,
  state:"odisha",
  Longitude: 23.007897,
  Name: "Jaipur"
}]
var temp = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({},dataSet));
var arr = JSON.parse(temp)
console.log(arr)




var my_columns = [];

$.each( dataSet[0], function( key, value ) {
        var my_item = {};
        my_item.data = key;
        my_item.title = key;
        my_columns.push(my_item);
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
   
    "columns": my_columns,
     data:dataSet
  });
});
```